# Elastic Beanstalk: Can't deploy to Windows server, and EB doesn't pull any logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Elastic Beanstalk running a Windows Server, with IIS, from and AMI I made. It launches great, no errors.

But when I try to deploy (form command line), I get this:

```
...
INFO: Creating AppVersion app-9e98-160212_104939
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances successfully.    
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: ServiceError - Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

When I try to pull the last 100 lines of error logs, it doesn't pull anything at all.

I checked the size of the packaged app, and the zip is only 60MB so it's not a size issue.

The project is just a bunch of php files, so I'm wondering if it just doesn't like the project for some reason.

Any ideas or suggestions on tracking down the issue? I'd really appreciate any guidance, I'm at a loss.

Additionally, I can't find any info on what directory this is going to deploy to. How do I know, and how do I change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, I don't know if something is wrong with your custom AMI, but what you can do to analyze the problem is:

1. RDP into your instance
2. cmd
3. `cd \cfn\log`
4. Look at the files cfn-init*.log

As the files are encoded with a Unix CRLF, they're almost unreadable with Notepad. I suggest that you use `type cfn-init.log` on the command line. This has helped me several times to localize the problem with the deployment. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have that cfn directory, as I'm not using CloudFormation. Would there be another log to look at for elastic beanstalk?

Comment: I see your answer now, I thought you had the normal AMI as base. Normally, there's is a CFN directory in the root which contains log files. I hope you were able to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as I set the bounty, I figured it out.

I had been adding the --verbose flag hoping for more details, but instead I needed the --debug flag which lead me in the right direction.

The problem was that I have Python 3.5 locally which is not supported by the ELB CI.